Has anyone learned Sanskrit from the source provided below?
Has anyone learned Sanskrit from this playlist? Is it good for learning sanskrit, it's complicated grammar rules,writing and overally? And can I follow only this playlist to develop my sanskrit so that I am able to understand, Purans, Ramayan, Gita,, and (Veda)? If it's not suitable which is the best one for learning sanskirt? and I can give short time daily. 

This is not the platform to present ideas or frame questions in a non- serious manner.
